# Are there any natural phenomena that use quantum entanglement

Tags: everyday-life, quantum-entanglement

I am aware that there are a growing number of natural phenomena that can now be understood as using quantum effects - from photosynthesis to migration navigation of some birds.
Is there any known process where nature is using quantum entanglement in any way?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "natural process"? For example, electron-positron annihilation, which produces a pair of entangled photons, happens all the time from the decay of positron-emitting radioisotopes in the Earth's crust like potassium-40 (and in many astrophysical processes as well); since these processes weren't set up by humans, most people on this site would label them as "natural phenomena", even though you might mean something else when you use the phrase.

Comment: Does the existence of all ordinary matter count?

Comment: You're going to have to narrow down what you mean by "using quantum entanglement" otherwise this question is hopelessly broad.